# How to get a Context in a static method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

What I am trying to achieve is to use a static class so that I can use it in all the pages/chtml. I have a table that will hold information like `SiteName` etc.

Usage of this would look like this:

```
@EnvTitles.GetPageInfo("sitename");
```

In the static class I need to produce this from a database table.
Here is what I have:

```
public class EnvTitles
{
    private readonly GeneralEntities db = new GeneralEntities();

    public static string GetPageInfo(string info)
    {
        string ReturnVal = string.Empty;
        
        switch (info)
        {
            case "sitename":
                var site = db.SiteDescriptions.Where(x => x.Title == "Site Name").Single();
                ReturnVal = site.Text;
                break;

            default:
                ReturnVal = "";
                break;

        }

        return ReturnVal;
    }
}
```

The problem is it does not like `db` - "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'EnvTitles.db'"

While searching I found an answer for this. Include the `Context` in the in the public static string. Like this:

```
public static string GetPageInfo(string info, GeneralEntities context)
{
        string ReturnVal = string.Empty;
        
        switch (info)
        {
            case "sitename":
                var site = context.SiteDescriptions.Where(x => x.Title == "Site Name").Single();
                ReturnVal = site.Text;
                break;

            default:
                ReturnVal = "";
                break;

        }

        return ReturnVal;
}
```

Which works, however now my ref to this on the page is expecting something in that place.

```
@EnvTitles.GetPageInfo("sitename", "Something Here!");
```

So there is nothing to put here. I tried just putting `null` there but when I ran the project it came back with context returned null.

Is there anyway to do this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Send as method argument

Comment: @mohsen Could you be a little more clear what you mean? Maybe some sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by doing this:

```
  public static string GetPageInfo(string info)
    {
        string ReturnVal = string.Empty;
        var context = new GeneralEntities();
        switch (info)
        {
            case "sitename":
                var site = context.SiteDescriptions.Where(x => x.Title == "Site Name").Single();
                ReturnVal = site.Text;
                break;

            default:
                ReturnVal = "";
                break;

        }

        return ReturnVal;
    }
```

With the link on the page staying the same:

```
@EnvTitles.GetPageInfo("sitename")
```

Now I can add as many cases that I want and change the the link to that case.
Thanks to all that helped!

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to pass the db context into your method like this

```cs
public static string GetPageInfo(string info, GeneralEntities db)
```

then create the `GeneralEntities` object in the calling cshtml so that it has the scope of the request.  Your call will then look something like this in cshtml

```
@{
   var db = new GeneralEntities();
}

@EnvTitles.GetPageInfo("sitename", db);
```

There are many other ways to implement what you're trying to do but this is the most straight-forward, un-opinionated way.

Comment: Ugh, I thought it was something like this. I was trying to save myself a bunch of code writing in each page. For something like SiteName, if I wanted that to show up on every page. I would have to add that to every page.  It was so much easier to do this using Identity.Claims. All I had to put in the pages was what I wanted to show up.

Comment: Like I said, there are several other ways to do this.  You could start by using a partial view and then all you have to do is paste that in where you need it

Comment: This will not work. In order to do that you have to add @Using BaseProject.GeneralDTO. doing that gives me an error on the page of - cannot convert from 'string' to 'BaseProject.GeneralDTO.GeneralEntities

Comment: your partial can do all of that work so you don't have to add a `using` statement everywhere.